# What is the recommended way to create a Custom Sink for AWS Sagemaker Feature Store in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-sagemaker, aws-feature-store

I want to create a Custom Apache Flink Sink to AWS Sagemaker Feature store, but there is no documentation for how to create custom sinks on Flink's website. There are also multiple base classes that I can potentially extend (e.g. `AsyncSinkBase`, `RichSinkFunction`), so I'm not sure which to use.

I am looking for guidelines regarding how to implement a custom sink (both in general and for my specific use-case). For my specific use-case: Sagemaker Feature Store has a synchronous client with a putRecord call to send records to AWS Sagemaker FS, so I am ideally looking for a way to create a custom sink that would work well with this client. Note: I require at `at least once` processing guarantees, as Sagemaker FS is DynamoDB (a key-value store) under the hood.

- Java Client: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sagemakerfeaturestoreruntime/AmazonSageMakerFeatureStoreRuntime.html
- Example of the putRecord call using the Python client: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-feature-store-streaming-aggregation/blob/main/src/lambda/StreamingIngestAggFeatures/lambda_function.py#L31

**What I've Found so Far**

- Some older articles which say to use `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.RichSinkFunction` and `SinkFunction`
- Some connectors using classes in `org.apache.flink.connector.base.sink.writer` (e.g. `AsyncSinkWriter`, `AsyncSinkBase`)
- This section of the Flink docs says to use the `SourceReaderBase` from `org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader` when creating custom sources; SourceBaseReader seems to be the equivalent source to the sink classes in the bullet above

Any help/guidance/insights are much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is missing in your list are the requirements around processing guarantees: do you need none, do you need at-least-once or exactly-once?

Comment: Updated my post: I require at-least-once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about extending RichAsyncFunction ?

you can find similar example here  - *https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/asyncio/#async-io-api*

Comment: What Sucheth said. For most endpoints with a client making HTTP requests, using Flink's Async IO is going to be the easiest and most performant way to integrate. I don't know whether SageMaker supports idempotent writes, so you might not be able to support exactly once.

Comment: Does Async IO work given that the Sagemaker client is synchronous?